# How do I plot multiple columns on the same plot with a legend using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

If a have a data frame that has columns names of:

```
x   y1   y2   y3
```

and I want a line plot with 3 different colored lines, y1, y2 and y3 plotted against x, how do I do this with ggplot and how do I add a legend that has the column names with their corresponding colors?

Comment: What have you tried, what are the coding problems you are experiencing? Please make your question reproducible [MRE]: paste a sample of your data into the question with  `dput(your_df)`. Consider putting the data into long format using `tidyr::pivot_longer()`